# Sorting a list of ints while ignoring sign [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to sort a list of ints, where the desired behavior is

```
input:  [-2, 1, 4, -5]
output: [1, -2, 4, -5]
```

Treating it as a list of strings doesn't work, and neither does treating it as a list of ints as they return

```
string: [-2, -5, 1, 4]
ints:   [-5, -2, 1, 4]
```

Any pointers on how to received the desired behavior?

Comment: How would you like `[-2, 1, 2, -2, 4, -5]` to be sorted? `[1, 2, -2, -2, 4, -5]`, `[1, -2, -2, 2, 4, -5]`, or any arbitrary order for number with same `abs` value?

Comment: Any arbitrary order with the same abs value is fine :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a `key` function that takes the absolute value to create the sort key for each item. Conveniently, Python has such a function built-in: `abs()`.

```
original = [-2, 1, 4, -5]
original.sort(key=abs)
```

Comment: My only comment is not to overwrite the reserved name `input`.

Comment: You're right. I did that to match the question, but I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Python allows you to use a custom sort key.
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/python-sorted/

I would suggest you define a function that calculates the absolute value (or the second power) of the number, and simply use that as the sort key.